# What is the benefit of storing data in databases like SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

This is very elementary question but why does a framework like Rails use ActiveRecord to run SQL commands to get data from a DB? I heard that you can cached data on the Rails server itself, so why not just store all data on the the server instead of the DB? Is it because space on the server is a lot more expensive/valuable than on the DB? If so, why is that? Also can the reason be that you want a ORM in the DB and that just takes too much code to set up on the Rails server? Sorry if this question sounds dumb but I don't know where else I can go for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

databases hold a substantial amount of advantages against other types of databases. Some of them are listed below:

- Data integrity is maximised and data redundancy is minimised, as
  the single storing place of all the data also implies that a given
  set of data only has one primary record. This aids in the maintaining
  of data as accurate and as consistent as possible and enhances data
  reliability.
- Generally bigger data security, as the single data storage location
  implies only a one possible place from which the database can be
  attacked and sets of data can be stolen or tampered with.
- Better data preservation than other types of databases due to
  often-included fault-tolerant setup.
- Easier for using by the end-user due to the simplicity of having a
  single database design.
- Generally easier data portability and database administration. More
  cost effective than other types of database systems as labour, power
  supply and maintenance costs are all minimised.
- Data kept in the same location is easier to be changed, re-organised,
  mirrored, or analysed.
- All the information can be accessed at the same time from the same
  location.
- Updates to any given set of data are immediately received by every
  end-user.

Answer (score 1):

What if some other program/person wants to access this data and for some reason cannot use your rails application? What if in future you decide to discontinue using rails and decide to go with some other technology for front end but want to keep the data? In these cases having a separate database helps. Also could you run complex join queries on cached data on Rail Server?